# WebGL large texture causes hidden stalling in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

When initializing a large (4096 x 4096) texture in WebGL on Windows 10 (with Three.js) the main thread of chrome stalls for an appreciable amount of time while the profiler shows nothing happening.

Here's an example profile of a 4096 x 4096 texture:
[image]

The "plateau" at a little before 1500ms is a call to `texImage2D` in Three.js and WebGL, then the `requestAnimationFrame` code gets called twice before the phantom gap shows up.

What causes this? Is there something happening with the underlying WebGL code in chrome that the profiler isn't reporting? Why does the call to `texImage2D` take 90 ms, and then the blank spot happens? I would expect all the work involving loading the texture to the GPU to happen there.

[Here is a link](https://brenden-morales.github.io/WebGL-Texture-Test/) that should reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem here is with `requestAnimationFrame`. Here's two profiles to illustrate

`requestAnimationFrame`:

[image]

`setTimeout`:

[image]

This seems like a fairly huge problem since most WebGL tutorials that exist mention that `requestAnimationFrame` is the "correct" way to do an animation loop.

Updated [demo](https://brenden-morales.github.io/WebGL-Texture-Test/) here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whats going on here. You do stall the gpu with that upload for a fixed amount of time, loop or no loop. I think the RAF does more stuff than just setTimeout which should be completely agnostic of what you do ( render or something else ). With RAF you've probably halted your app logic until that queue is processed. With set timeout you are probably still issuing commands. Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well 4096 x 4096 is a large texture and it takes some time to transfer all the data to the GPU. If you are calling `texImage2D` then `drawArrays` immediately, the `drawArray` can not be executed until the uploading in the `texImage2D` is done. This explains the delay you are seeing in the profiler.

Comment: You would expect the `texImage2D` call to be filling up that space then, no?

Comment: @Brenden No because webgl calls only fill up a command queue for GPU, which has little to do with the actual time required to do something.